# How can I get the current region id inside the 'hook_preprocess_block'?

Tags: drupal, hook, block, preprocessor, theming

How can I get the current region ID inside `hook_preprocess_block()`?
I tried the following code, but it seems something is wrong.

```
function ThemeName_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['elements']['#region'] == "nav") {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'SomeStyle';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$region = $variables['elements']['#configuration']['region'];`